# Adding text into a created file

Tags: linux

I'll try and explain my issue as easy as possible.

I have made a script which unzips a file and then takes the data from the resulting files and sorts them into appropriate folders.  I am now struggling with one specific part.

My script needs to output a file that contains a label for each directory and the files need to be sorted in reversible order.  So far I have this:

```
#firstly changes to correct directory and then creates a file that contains a list of all the files in that directory sorted by size order

    cd processFiles/$type1
    ls -S > orderSize1.txt 
    cd ../$type2
    ls -S > orderSize2.txt
    cd ../$type3
    ls -S > orderSize3.txt
    cd ../misc
    ls -S > orderSize4.txt

    #lists file types by reverse alphabetical order
    cd ../$type1
    ls -r > tempfile1.txt

    cd ../$type2
    ls -r > tempfile2.txt

    cd ../$type3
    ls -r > tempfile3.txt

    cd ../misc
    ls -r > tempfile4.txt
```

So in the file I need to have it listed reverse alphabetically (which is done in my script already) but how do I put in comments saying 'these are the jpg files' or 'these are all the gif files.'?

I also need to write a separate clean up script for this, but I think that is quite easy - not too sure on it though.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: sorry just realised my formatting is horrible, not used this resource much before but I shall try to improve it.

Comment: Select your code and press the `{}` button to format as code (this is the same as indenting it by four spaces)

Comment: excellent, cheers.  I've changed it now so hopefully it looks a bit better.

Comment: `echo "this is ..." > file`

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you're using bash. Other shells may do things a little differently.

As karakfa noted in a comment, you can use the echo command along with redirection to print a message to a file. For example:

```
echo "These are the jpeg files." > jpegfiles.txt
```

Then, when you run your ls command, you would use append redirection to add the results to the file:

```
ls -r >> jpegfiles.txt
```